# parse json in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, postman

i want to show "port_image" in my carousel image slider.
and this data is still one, i just want to try to show it.

this is my json structure data response.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "port_id": 4,
    "name": brand port,
    "data_port_image": [
        {
            "port_image_title": "ship | Port Image",
            "port_image_description": "shipport| Port Image",
            "port_image": "https://cdn.shopimg.com/imgport/port.png"
        }
    ]
},
"message": "Success Get Data"
}
```

below is my future async API.

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
var response = await http.post(
    'https://urlship/v_ship/port_detail');
return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}
```

and below is my displayer code.

```
var _slideImage = Container(
  height: 222.0,
  child: FutureBuilder<Map>(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? new ImageSlide(
              list: snapshot.data['data'],
            )
          : new Container();
    },
  ),
);

class ImageSlide extends StatelessWidget {
final List list;
ImageSlide({this.list});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Container(
      height: 222.0,
      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        dotColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
        dotSize: 5.5,
        dotSpacing: 16.0,
        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
        showIndicator: true,
        overlayShadow: true,
        overlayShadowColors: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
        overlayShadowSize: 0.9,
        images: [
          NetworkImage(
            list[i]['data_port_image'],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

how to parse and display "port_image" json data with flutter?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need slight modification and that is because

```
 NetworkImage(
   list[i]['data_port_image'],
),
```

First your `list` variable is a `Map` not a list, so update it like this `list['data_port_image']` and then,

`data_port_image` is also a `Map`, so to access to the image url of that map using `"port_image"` as follows,

```
 NetworkImage(
   list['data_port_image'][i]["port_image"],
),
```

I strongly recommend you to create a model class and map your json model to that dart model class (PODO). [Read more about this in Do](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)c (A elegant tutorial).

Comment: i got error like this. type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' what is that mean?

Comment: @Aphron updated the answer `list['data_port_image'][i]["port_image"]`

Comment: i think its works. but i got a new error here haha. RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Comment: @Aphron now your `itemCount` should be `list['data_port_image']`

Comment: excuse me sir, @Blasanka. can i have your account? so i will contact you if i need some help. :)

Comment: What did you mean by account? you can visit my website where you can find how to contact me: https:blasanka.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

To convert JSON in Flutter:

My JSON:

```
{
    "id": "RTPDM",
    "bookmarks": [
        {
            "google.com",
            "facebook.com",
            "stackoverflow.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Object:

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final List<String> bookmarks;

  User({this.id, [this.bookmarks]);

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
       id: json['id'],
       bookmarks: List.from(json['bookmarks']));
  }
}
```

Then:

```
 Future<User> getUser() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('https://my_url.com');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load user');
    }
  }
```

If you need more explanation, I recommend you to follow this link: [Flutter JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

Comment: thank you for answering sir. but i think i got the answer. :)